# No Activity found to handle intent errors

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am stumped, I get No Activity to handle intent, I have checked the manifest etc. Can someone have a quick look at this and see what I am doing wrong here.

This is my java class

```
'import com.one2.indoor.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Menu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageButton tut1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activitymain);
    tut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity (new Intent("com.indoor.ActivityMain"));
        }
    });

        }'
```

This is my ActivityMain class

```
'import com.one2.indoor.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

}

}'
```

and finally my manifest

```
'<activity
        android:name="com.indoor.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.indoor.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.indoor.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.indoor.ActivityMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.indoor.ACTIVITYMAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.indoor.ActivityMain" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I just cant see it, why I'm getting the error. Any help be much appreciated

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your time, I really appreciate you trying to help me out, unfortunately none of the above has fixed the issue,
I have tried all of it. 
When I change the manifest from com.indoor.ActivityMain to .ActivityMain or com.one2.indoor.Activity min it will not run in the emiluator.
So I leave it at com.indoor,ActivityMain
I have removed the <IntentFilter></IntentFilter>
I have tried to change the intent in the java etc, no joy

Comment: FIXED!!in my java I had the widget for button not ImageButton, changed Button to ImageButton and imported the imageButton widget, works, thanks for the advise guys, if anything learned what not to do aso from your words, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The path to your activity in the manifest and your startActivity is possibly incorrect. It should be com.one2.indoor.ActivityMain, or whatever is specified as its package.

Alternatively, I think you can just put .ActivityMain in the manifest for the name, and it will figure out the path automatically.

Finally, try using startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, TargetActivity.class))

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your time, I really appreciate you trying to help me out, unfortunately none of the above has fixed the issue,
I have tried all of it. 
When I change the manifest from com.indoor.ActivityMain to .ActivityMain or com.one2.indoor.Activity min it will not run in the emiluator.
So I leave it at com.indoor,ActivityMain
I have removed the <IntentFilter></IntentFilter>
I have tried to change the intent in the java etc, no joy

Answer (score 0):

Like synergy8 said and you should accept his answer but you need a new intent in the android manifest declared by a new activity.

So to be more clear you should see your manifest have something like  this sorry im doing this on a mobilr smart phone

```
              <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" > //your activity name replaces .main activity
        <intent-filter >
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

That should do it, if you look at the first activity created there u will see it, just copy and paste it and changr the .main in the intent filter and the .mainactivity that it has in the activity

Basically from what I see and what synergy said you are importing a package that does not exist?  Com.indoor.activity , when your package is com.one2.indoor.activity

Comment: P.s. Sorry that's not how you comment in xml

Answer (score 0):

First, action strings are case-sensitive. `"com.indoor.ActivityMain"` does not equal `"com.indoor.ACTIVITYMAIN"`.

Second, you probably do not want those extra `<intent-filter>` elements anyway. *Only* put an `<intent-filter>` on an activity if you want third-party apps to invoke that activity directly (e.g., your `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activity). Otherwise, get rid of the `<intent-filter>` and use the `Intent` structure pointed out by Synergy807: `startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityMain.class))`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be com.one2.indoor.ActivityMain.Also make sure that the names should be exactly same as they are case sensitive.